# JOIN - Dúvida de Principiante

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma dúvida acerca do `full outer join`, pesquisei e continuo sem entender. A última figura abaixo explica, graficamente, o funcionamento do `full outer join`, que retorna apenas os dados não coincidentes nas duas tabelas(tabela empresa, na primeira figura, e tabela funcionario, na segunda figura).
Reparem que as chaves 123, 1230000 ocorrem tanto na tabela empresa(primeira tabela, com apenas dois registros), quanto na tabela funcionário(segunda tabela, com 6 registros).
Já as chaves 12300 e 123000 ocorrem somente na tabela funcionário. Uma vez que elas não têm ocorrência na outra tabela, a consulta que eu faço com o comando abaixo deveria retornar apenas as linhas com as chaves 12300 e 123000. No entanto, retornam apenas duas linhas de `null`? O que pode estar acontecendo? O comando que estou usando está logo abaixo:

```
SELECT pessoaID, ultimoNome, cidade
FROM empresa e
FULL OUTER JOIN funcionario f
ON e.pessoaID = f.personID 
WHERE e.pessoaID is NULL
OR  f.personID  is NULL
```

[image: Tabela Empresa]

[image: Tabela Funcionário]

[image: Full Outer Join - Explicação gráfica]

Figura 1: Tabela Empresa
Figura 2: Tabela Funcionário
Figura 3: Explicão gráfica do `outer join`

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN dá como resultado todas as linhas das tabelas que atendem ao critério de junção, mais uma linha para cada linha da tabela da esquerda que não atende aos critérios da junção (com NULLs nos campos referentes à tabela da direita) e mais uma linha para cada linha da tabela da direita que não atende aos critérios da junção (com NULLs nos campos referentes à tabela da esquerda).
Ou seja todas as linha que atendem os critérios da INNER JOIN, mais todas as linhas das tabelas para as quais não existe correspondência, com NULLs nos campos da tabela sem correspondência.

Answer (score 1):

Eu te desencorajaria de usar a função full outer join, ela é a mais rara e muitas vezes chata de usar, tem alguns casos em que é usada. Normalmente, em relatórios de exceção ou ETL ou outras situações muito peculiares em que ambos os lados possuem dados que você está tentando combinar.
A melhor alternativa é usar um INNER JOIN, um LEFT JOIN (com o lado direito IS NULL) e um RIGHT JOIN (com o lado esquerdo IS NULL) e fazer um UNION - às vezes esta abordagem é melhor porque você pode customizar cada junção individualmente de forma mais óbvia ( e adicionar uma coluna derivada para indicar qual lado é encontrado ou se é encontrado em ambos e qual deles vai "ganhar").

Comment: Ok, para o que eu pretendia fazer, ela se encaixaria. Mas vou usar como mederação. Grato.